# Pass environment object to all views in the stack SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using Firebase for authentication in my application. When a user signs in they will have a session. My goal is to pass that session to all views in my stack so I can pull that users data for various API calls and such. Currently, I am passing the session environment variable to the TabView in my application so that all tabs have access to this session.

Here is my session class.

```
class Session: ObservableObject {
    let auth = Auth.auth()

    @Published var signedIn = false
    
    var isSignedIn: Bool {
        return auth.currentUser != nil
    }
}
```

In my app struct I have the following views setup:

```
struct app: App {

    @StateObject var session = Session()

    TabView {
        // Tabs redacted for easy viewing
    }
    .environmentObject(session)
}
```

And finally a view I am hoping to use this session environment object in.

```
struct NewListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: Session

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(session.$signedIn)
        }
    }
}
```

My expectation here is that I should be able to just print to the screen whether the sessions signedIn is true or false. However, I am getting this error:

> Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Published.Publisher' conform to 'StringProtocol'

Am I understanding environment variables incorrectly here?

Comment: `Text()` takes in a string. `session.$signedIn` is something like a `Binding<Bool>`, which is completely different. Maybe you meant `Text(String(session.signedIn))`?

Comment: Maybe you were looking for something like this `Text($session.auth.wrappedValue ?? "")`

Comment: @aheze Absolutely rookie mistake by me. Thanks so much that did the trick. Submit an answer so I can give you full credit!

Answer (score 0):

Remove $

```
struct NewListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: Session

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(session.signedIn)")
        }
    }
}
```